# how to play AVVideoComposition in AVPlayer?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift5

hi everyone i have been creating an iOS video editing app.i have created an AVVideoComposition that consists of two layers.now i want to play this composition in AVPlayer.as AVVideoComposition is not an asset so how can i play this in AVPlayer?
here is the sample code i have been trying.i have heard about AVVideoCompositionCoreAnimation but that also didn't work.

```
let backgroundLayer = CoverView.layer
let videoLayer = VideoView.layer
let parentLayer = CALayer()
    parentLayer.frame = CGRect(x:20.0 , y: 20.0, width: CoverView.frame.width, height: CoverView.frame.height)
    parentLayer.addSublayer(backgroundLayer)
    parentLayer.addSublayer(videoLayer)


    let composition = AVMutableVideoComposition()

    composition.animationTool = AVVideoCompositionCoreAnimationTool(postProcessingAsVideoLayer: videoLayer, in: parentLayer)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can init AVPlayer with AVPlayerItem which allows composition as input thus can be played without exporting.

```
let item = AVPlayerItem(asset: composition)
let player = AVPlayer(playerItem: item)
```

Answer (score 0):

you need an exporter method for this.in AVExportSession there is a method export did finish.in this method you will be able to generate a url for your video file.like this

```
func exportDidFinish(_ session: AVAssetExportSession) {

     guard
        session.status == AVAssetExportSession.Status.completed,
        let outputURL = session.outputURL
        else {
          return
      }

        self.avplayer = AVPlayer(url: outputURL)

               playerController.player = self.avplayer
               self.addChild(playerController)
               view.addSubview(playerController.view)
               playerController.view.frame = view.bounds
               playerController.showsPlaybackControls = false
              avplayer.isMuted = false
```

Answer (score 0):

You can play AVMutableComposition, but not AVMutableVideoComposition. But you can use your AVMutableVideoComposition as AVPlayerItem's videoComposition property.

```
let composition = AVMutableComposition()
    
//add and configure tracks here    

let videoComposition = AVMutableVideoComposition()
videoComposition.animationTool = AVVideoCompositionCoreAnimationTool(postProcessingAsVideoLayer: videoLayer, in: parentLayer)

let item = AVPlayerItem(asset: composition)
item.videoComposition = videoComposition
let player = AVPlayer(playerItem: item)
```